# ImportError: No module named filters

Tags: python, scikit-image

I installed skimage in ubuntu terminal using command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-skimage
```

it installed succesfully but when using it in my code (`from skimage.filters import threshold_local`). i get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scan.py", line 4, in <module>
    from skimage.filters import threshold_local
ImportError: No module named filters
```

kindly someone help me to correct this!

Comment: Do this: `import sys; print sys.path`. Does the path to your installation of `skimage` appear there? If not, then add it and continue or consult your nearest google search for how to properly install `skimage`. If it does appear there, update your post

Comment: If you need help with the search for `skimage`, do this (assuming unix environment): `find $(python -c 'import sys; print "\n".join(sys.path)') -iname '*skimage*'`. You might have to run it with `sudo`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Troble importing filters using skimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33686005/troble-importing-filters-using-skimage)

Comment: running above command and getting :    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skimage
find: ‘/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old’: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skimage

Comment: So it looks like it found a file called `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skimage`. Don't worry about the missing `/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old`, I also got that error when I ran the command. What this means is that you have `skimage` (atleast something with the name `skimage`) installed, but you might be importing it the wrong way. You need to be doing `from skimage import filter`, as opposed to how you do it now - **note _filter_ not _filters_**. Checkout the `duplicate` link I posted, there is a chance you are doing the import wrong

Comment: It could be that you have a very old version of skimage; as smac89 mentions, the filter module got renamed to filters quite a while ago.

Comment: Now I import filter module as you mentioned above and getting:   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scan.py", line 63, in <module>
    T = filter.threshold_local(warped, 11, offset = 10, method = "gaussian")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'threshold_local'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is resolved now :D. What I found is that there is no module named 'filters' in skimage '**0.10.1**' as it has '**filter**'. So, when I upgraded it using the command

> sudo pip install --upgrade scikit-image

to version '**0.13.1**', it comes with the '**filters**' module instead of 'filter'. The 'filters' module has all attributes of thresholding including 'local' and others as well.

Answer (score 0):

So I got same problem in Spyder, Python 3.6.6.

this code (with img being a np array):

```
import skimage
val = skimage.filters.threshold_otsu(img)
```

gives: ***module 'skimage' has no attribute 'filters'***

I tried *pip install --upgrade scikit-image* with no change. Skimage is indeed in my system path:
*'C:\WPy-3661\python-3.6.6.amd64\lib\site-packages', and the filters folder is in there with the **init** file.

but if i do:

```
from skimage import filters as anything
val = skimage.filters.threshold_otsu(img)
```

then it works. This is not normal, right ?

Note that in my sys.path paths there is only one skimage folder. So I don't think it's a duplicate issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had also same problem but below code helped me:

```
!sudo apt-get install python-skimage
from skimage.filters import  roberts, prewitt, sobel, scharr, laplace
```