# AttributeError: module 'skimage' has no attribute 'filters'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import skimage

my_image = cv2.imread('my_image.jpeg', 1)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(my_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
b = skimage.filters.threshold_local(gray,19,offset=10)
b = Image.fromarray(b)
b = b.convert("L")
b.save('adaptive_output.png')
```

But I receive the following error:

```
b = skimage.filters.threshold_local(gray,19,offset=10)
AttributeError: module 'skimage' has no attribute 'filters'
```

I am using Python 3.8 and the scikit-image version on my system is 0.18.1. I also tried the code in different IDE's but received the error everywhere.
I have also checked [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216075/importerror-no-module-named-filters), [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248017/cannot-find-reference-xxx-in-init-py-python-pycharm) and [question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479696/pycharm-unresolved-reference-error-on-the-ide-when-opening-a-working-project) but none of their answers worked.

Comment: Do you have another file called `skimage.py` in your project?

Comment: @RandomDavis I checked and I confirm there is no file called `skimage.py` in my project. Should it be or shouldn't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try importing specific attributes. Like this:

```
from skimage import filters
```